# libvirt-bin error on a VM when I try to list VM

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, openstack, arch-linux, virsh

I'm using Virtualbox 4.3.18 on my Arch Linux Host machine and libvirt-bin 1.2.9 on my Ubuntu Server Cloud guest machine. Everytime I try to follow [this tutorial](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/nodes.html#virtual-machine-nodes) I receive the following error when I run virsh:

Command:

```
virsh -c vbox+ssh://leandro@10.0.3.15/system list --all
```

Error:

```
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: internal error: unable to initialize VirtualBox driver API
```

Someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you `ssh` to the IP address 10.0.3.15 as the user leandro?

Comment: Yes, I can ssh to his IP.

Answer (score 0):

Your installation of libvirtd needs to be configured to handle the vbox+ssh connection type. Details on how to do this are covered here, titled: [VirtualBox hypervisor driver](http://libvirt.org/drvvbox.html).

There's a sample domain XML config that you'll need to load into libvirtd so that it knows how to talk to the VirtualBox VM.

*excerpt - sample config*

```
<domain type='vbox'>
  <name>vbox</name>
  <uuid>4dab22b31d52d8f32516782e98ab3fa0</uuid>

  <os>
    <type>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    <boot dev='fd'/>
    <boot dev='network'/>
  </os>

  <memory>654321</memory>
  <vcpu>1</vcpu>

  <features>
    <pae/>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
  </features>

  <devices>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <source file='/home/user/Downloads/slax-6.0.9.iso'/>
      <target dev='hdc'/>
      <readonly/>
    </disk>

    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <source file='/home/user/tmp/vbox.vdi'/>
      <target dev='hdd'/>
    </disk>

    <disk type='file' device='floppy'>
      <source file='/home/user/tmp/WIN98C.IMG'/>
      <target dev='fda'/>
    </disk>

    <filesystem type='mount'>
      <source dir='/home/user/stuff'/>
      <target dir='my-shared-folder'/>
    </filesystem>

    <!--BRIDGE-->
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <source bridge='eth0'/>
      <mac address='00:16:3e:5d:c7:9e'/>
      <model type='am79c973'/>
    </interface>

    <!--NAT-->
    <interface type='user'>
      <mac address='56:16:3e:5d:c7:9e'/>
      <model type='82540eM'/>
    </interface>

    <sound model='sb16'/>

    <parallel type='dev'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target port='0'/>
    </parallel>

    <parallel type='dev'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/2'/>
      <target port='1'/>
    </parallel>

    <serial type="dev">
      <source path="/dev/ttyS0"/>
      <target port="0"/>
    </serial>

    <serial type="pipe">
      <source path="/tmp/serial.txt"/>
      <target port="1"/>
    </serial>

    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb'>
      <source>
        <vendor id='0x1234'/>
        <product id='0xbeef'/>
      </source>
    </hostdev>

    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb'>
      <source>
        <vendor id='0x4321'/>
        <product id='0xfeeb'/>
      </source>
    </hostdev>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Save this to a file, say `my.xml`, on your system and then use `virsh` to import it.

```
$ virsh create my.xml
```

**NOTE:** You'll also need the libvirt daemon driver installed. On Fedora 20 it's in a package called: `libvirt-daemon-driver-vbox`.  You'll need `libvirt-daemon` along with the interface, `libvirt-daemon-driver-interface`. I would assume there are similar packages that provide these on ArchLinux.

#### References

[KVM/Virsh - Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Virsh)

Comment: I couldn't find any of this packages for Arch and Ubuntu.

Comment: Their names will likely be different. Relax your searches using pacman. Look for libvirt.

Comment: There are only 3 packages: libvirt, libvirt-glib and libvirt-python

Comment: @Leandro_GS - Then you may not be able to make use of libvirt on Arch if it doesn't have these packages. You cannot do what you want without the vbox driver for libvirt.

Comment: Looks like these packages are [all included](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/libvirt) on "libvirt" package. `libvirt is a virtualization API and a daemon for managing virtual machines (VMs) -- remote or locally, using multiple virtualization back-ends (QEMU/KVM, VirtualBox, Xen, etc), communally called hypervisors .`

Comment: @Leandro_GS - yes that possibly sounds like everything is included. Be aware that libvirtd is a generic interface from which you can manage many different backend technologies, so that description may be saying just that. Using `pacman` you should be able to list out an inventory of what's included.

Comment: I think [this](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/libvirt/) is the list

Comment: @Leandro_GS - looking in my package for vbox the library is called: `/usr/lib64/libvirt/connection-driver/libvirt_driver_vbox.so`. Looking at that Arch pkg it too carries that same file, `usr/lib/libvirt/connection-driver/libvirt_driver_vbox.so`, so you should be all set.

Comment: I was thinking in use virt-manager instead virtualbox, but I am also having trouble to install it.

Comment: @Leandro_GS - sorry I don't use Arch so I can't really be of much more help on your original Q.